# Make every 2nd line bold

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following bash command that returns headline and URL pairs over 2 lines.

```
curl -s https://uk.reuters.com/assets/jsonWireNews |
 awk '/"url":|"headline":/' |
 cut -d'"' -f4 |
 awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {sub(/^/,"https://uk.reuters.com")} {print}'
```

For the first 3 headlines, this outputs:

```
'Hamilton' takes centre stage in London's West End
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-theatre-hamilton/hamilton-takes-centre-stage-in-londons-west-end-idUKKBN1EG02I
IAG among bidders chosen for Austrian airline Niki - sources
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-air-berlin-niki/iag-among-bidders-chosen-for-austrian-airline-niki-sources-idUKKBN1EG1BM
Oil eases from highs but OPEC cuts still support market
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-global-oil/oil-eases-from-highs-but-opec-cuts-still-support-market-idUKKBN1EG06G
```

I want to make the headlines i.e. every other line starting from the first, to be in bold:

```
'Hamilton' takes centre stage in London's West End
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-theatre-hamilton/hamilton-takes-centre-stage-in-londons-west-end-idUKKBN1EG02I  
IAG among bidders chosen for Austrian airline Niki - sources
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-air-berlin-niki/iag-among-bidders-chosen-for-austrian-airline-niki-sources-idUKKBN1EG1BM  
Oil eases from highs but OPEC cuts still support market
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-global-oil/oil-eases-from-highs-but-opec-cuts-still-support-market-idUKKBN1EG06G
```

Comment: You might want to include a small example input along with the corresponding desired output and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s https://uk.reuters.com/assets/jsonWireNews |
awk '/"url":|"headline":/' |
cut -d'"' -f4 |
awk '/^\// { print "\033[0mhttps://uk.reuters.com:" $0; next } {print "\033[1m" $0 }'
```

if match start of "^/" then print the bash escape for not-bold and then go to the next line.
default print prefixes each line with bash escape for bold.

Comment: This work thanks.  Is there a way of doing it without using a temp file?

Comment: yes, sorry temp file was to save network calls when testing.

Comment: I cleaned up the temp file reference.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea in the first version of the question, the problem just is how to get the control codes printed by `tput` to `awk` so it can print them.

Variables and command substitutions aren't expanded within single quotes (`''`), so we'd need to use double quotes. But using them with `awk` code may be awkward <sub>(no pun intended)</sub> since there might be other characters that need to be escaped. We could close the single quotes and start a double quoted string for the duration of the part we want expanded:

```
$ bold="$(tput bold)"
$ normal="$(tput sgr0)"
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\ndoo' | awk '{if (NR % 2) print "'"$bold"'" $0 "'"$normal"'"; else print;}'
foo
bar
doo
```

(In `"'"$bold"'"`, the first `"` is literal, part of the awk code, the `'` ends the single quoted string, `"` starts a double quoted string, and the other `"'"` sequence is the same in reverse.)

That's a bit ugly. The alternative is to pass the control codes to `awk` as variables:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\ndoo' | awk -vbold="$bold" -vnormal="$normal" '{if (NR % 2) print bold $0 normal; else print;}'
foo
bar
doo
```

(Of course we could pass them through the environment.)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at `man tput` I tried:

```
$ bold=`tput smso`  
$ normal=`tput rmso`
$ echo "${bold}Please type in your name: ${normal}\c"
```

And it appeared to work...  So that should give you enough to go on, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `<esc>[1m` will make text bold. So you can use sed to replace every second line starting from the first with itself, but `<esc>[1m` prepended and `<esc>[m` appended (to reset the formatting). Pipe it to

```
sed 's/.*/<esc>[1m&<esc>[m/;N'
```

where `<esc>` is `0x1b`.

Sed works line-by-line, operating on them one by one. First, sed encounters the first line, and performs the substitution `s/.*/<esc>[1m&<esc>[m/`. Then it performs the `N` commands, which joins the next line with this line (separated by a linefeed). On the iteration of the next input, sed skips the second line because it was joined to the first one, and proceeds to repeat the same process to the third line.

Comment: This is what I tried and it doesn't work:  
```curl -s https://uk.reuters.com/assets/jsonWireNews |
 awk '/"url":|"headline":/' |
 cut -d'"' -f4 |
 awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {sub(/^/,"https://uk.reuters.com")} {print}' |
 sed 's/.*/0x1b[1m&0x1b[m/;N'```

Comment: Did you use the text `0x1b` or the character with its code point at `0x1b`?

Comment: It works for me http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmV1U.png

Comment: I used the text `0x1b`.  I don't have `gsed`.

Comment: (`gsed` is macOS's equivalent of `sed`) Don't use the text `0x1b`, this represents the escape character, this can be typed using Ctrl+V Esc in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with `perl` using the `LWP`, `JSON`, and `Term::ANSIColor` modules.   `Term::ANSIColor` is a core perl module, but both `LWP` and `JSON` are [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/) modules.  They're very commonly used modules so are probably available pre-packaged for your distro (e.g. on debian etc, `apt-get install libjson-perl libwwww-perl`)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $bold = color('bold');
my $reset = color('reset');

my $base='https://uk.reuters.com'

foreach my $url (@ARGV) {
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
  my $res = $ua->request($req);
  if ($res->is_success) {
    foreach my $h ( @{ decode_json($res->content)->{headlines} }) {
      print $bold, $h->{headline}, $reset, "\n", $base, $h->{url}, "\n\n";
    };
  } else {
    die "Error processing '$url': ", $res->status_line, "\n";
  }
}
```

This doesn't need `curl` or `wget` or multiple invocations of `awk` and/or `cut` (that ugliness was what motivated me to write an answer - as a general rule, if you're piping `grep` or `awk` into themselves then you're doing it wrong.  ditto for piping `cut` or `grep` into `awk` - `awk` can do everything that those two can do and more.  As can `perl`), or anything else.

Save it as, e.g. `./bold-2nd.pl`, make it executable with `chmod`, and run it like this:

```
$ ./bold-2nd.pl https://uk.reuters.com/assets/jsonWireNews 
RBS to pay $125 million to settle California mortgage bond claims
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-rbs-settlement/rbs-to-pay-125-million-to-settle-california-mortgage-bond-claims-idUKKBN1EH053

Driver charged with attempted murder over Australian vehicle attack
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-australia-attack/driver-charged-with-attempted-murder-over-australian-vehicle-attack-idUKKBN1EH044

EasyJet says other airlines interested in feeder flights from Tegel
https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-air-berlin-m-a-easyjet/easyjet-says-other-airlines-interested-in-feeder-flights-from-tegel-idUKKBN1EH04W

[...]
```

This version of the script can handle multiple URLs on the command line (of course, they all need to return the same json-formatted data...or at least extremely similar with both a `headline` and a `url` field).

btw, I've made it print a blank line between each article. I find that to be more readable.

If you want to use `curl` to do the fetching rather than the perl `LWP` module, the script would be quite a bit simpler:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use JSON;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $bold = color('bold');
my $reset = color('reset');

my $base='https://uk.reuters.com'

undef $/;
my $json = <>; # slurp in entire stdin

foreach my $h ( @{ decode_json($json)->{headlines} }) {
  print $bold, $h->{headline}, $reset, "\n", $base, $h->{url}, "\n\n";
};
```

Run this version as:

```
$ curl -s https://uk.reuters.com/assets/jsonWireNew | ./bold-2nd.pl
```

Note that both versions of the bolding script use a json parser to actually parse the json data, rather than relying on regular expressions to search for lines matching particular patterns.  As has been noted many times before, parsing json, or html, or xml, or any similar structured data format with regular expressions is unreliable and fragile.  In the simple case, it can be made to work but even minor changes in the input format can break the script (e.g. if Reuters stops outputting pretty-printed json with line feeds between each data element and record, and starts printing just a single line of json, any line-based regexp pattern matcher will break)

Finally, the json data fetched by `curl` (or LWP) looks like this:

```
{ "headlines": [

{ "id": "UKKBN1EH044", 
  "headline": "Driver charged with attempted murder over Australian vehicle attack", 
  "dateMillis": "1514003249000", 
  "formattedDate": "3m ago",
  "url": "/article/uk-australia-attack/driver-charged-with-attempted-murder-over-australian-vehicle-attack-idUKKBN1EH044",
  "mainPicUrl": "https://s4.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20171223&t=2&i=1216634499&w=116&fh=&fw=&ll=&pl=&sq=&r=LYNXMPEDBM04W"
},
]}
```

so, `id`, `dateMillis`, `formattedDate`, and `mainPicURL` are also available for printing or other use in the perl `$h` hashref variable, as well as the `headline` and `url` that we're printing.